# Why won't sys/stat.h define ino_t with -std=c1x?

Tags: c, posix, standards, stat

I'm experiencing a strange problem with some C code I am writing. Consider the following code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
ino_t inode;
```

According to *POSIX.1-2008*, the header file *<sys/stat.h*> defines `ino_t`<sup>[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)</sup>:

> The *<sys/stat.h>* header shall define the `blkcnt_t`, `blksize_t`,  `dev_t`, `ino_t`, `mode_t`, `nlink_t`, `uid_t`, `gid_t`, `off_t`, and `time_t` types as described in *<sys/types.h>*.

This happens when I try to compile the source code above places in a file *test.c* on my Linux system:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <sys/stat.h>
ino_t inode;
$ uname -srm
Linux 3.8.0-26-generic x86_64
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
$ gcc -c test.c
$ gcc -std=c90 test.c
test.c:2:1: error: unknown type name 'ino_t'
$ gcc -std=c99 test.c     
test.c:2:1: error: unknown type name 'ino_t'
$ gcc -std=c1x test.c
test.c:2:1: error: unknown type name 'ino_t'
```

Why is the definition of `ino_t` not revelead when I specify any *-std* option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My manual page of `fstat` says to also include `sys/types.h`, and that solves the problem for me. The definition of `ino_t` in `sys/stat.h` is protected with the feature macros `__USE_XOPEN` and `__USE_XOPEN2K`. The definition in `sys/types.h` is not protected that way.

The manual page also says to include `unistd.h`, but that wasn't necessary to solve your problem.

According to the manual page of `feature_test_macros`:

> `__STRICT_ANSI__`
>                 ISO Standard C.  This macro is implicitly defined by gcc(1) when
>                 invoked with, for example, the `-std=c99` or `-ansi` flag.

I guess this means that any XOPEN features are also switched off. I could however not find any description of that.

P.S. It seems R.. (see below) feels that this is described also in the manual page of `feature_test_macros`, but my limited brain is not able to find the exact wording, so I'd like to leave that as an exercise to the reader. If it were described anywhere, then I would expect it in that manual page indeed.

Beware that the gist of this answer is as follows:

> Thou shall include **all** include files mentioned in a manual page and not try to reverse engineer which ones may not be needed.

Comment: Ah great. I just found out that apparently defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE to 200809L also does the trick.

Comment: @R.. I need one more hint, because I can still not find it.

Comment: @R.. Yes that looks very similar to my version, except for the `ftm` program that mine is lacking. I give up, so I've left it as a challenge to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Your program would have compiled without complaint if you had used `-std=gnuXX` instead of `-std=cXX`.

```
$ cc -std=c11 -fsyntax-only test.c ; echo $?
test.c:2:1: error: unknown type name ‘ino_t’; did you mean ‘__ino_t’?
1
```

but

```
$ cc -std=gnu11 -fsyntax-only test.c ; echo $?
0
```

Many people don't properly understand the effects of the `-std=cXX` options.  They do *not*, by themselves, tell GCC to be strictly conforming (e.g. diagnose all use of GNU extensions).  If you want strict conformance you must also give the options `-Wall -Wpedantic`.

There are only three differences between a `-std=cXX` mode and the corresponding `-std=gnuXX` mode, and two of them are usually not what you want:

1. [System-specific predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html) in the application namespace are disabled in `-std=cXX` mode.  This one is a Good Thing; application-namespace predefined macros are [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1?rq=1) at best, and at worst, break legitimate code.  However, it has been known to break system header files that are still looking for those macros.
2. [Trigraphs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html) are enabled in `-std=cXX` modes and disabled in `-std=gnuXX` modes.  You don't want trigraphs; they were already obsolete when they were invented, and IMNSHO they should have been removed from the C standard a very long time ago.
3. In `-std=cXX` mode, GNU libc will attempt to minimize the number of extensions above and beyond the specified C standard that are visible in its headers.  (Caution: many other C libraries that GCC can be used with will **not** do this.)  In the case of headers like `sys/stat.h` that aren't part of the C standard, this is taken to mean "expose only the features that were present in the oldest version of this header we support," which is often something very old and limited, like POSIX.1-1993.  This is what tripped you up.  You can work around it by defining [feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) to direct GNU libc to expose newer POSIX, etc. features.

If you are writing a new C program from scratch, I recommend you use `-Wall` and `-Wpedantic` (and probably a bunch of other [`-W` switches](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)) but I do *not* recommend the use of `-std=cXX`, as the only *positive* effect is to turn off the system-specific predefines, and that can break system headers.  It is also almost always less hassle to go straight for `_GNU_SOURCE` or equivalent than to futz around with trying to find a `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` setting that gives you everything you need (particularly if you, or third-party code you bundle, might use deprecated-but-still-commonplace functions like `gettimeofday`).