# Why does the 1987 Korn oneliner print unix?

Tags: c, deobfuscation

OK, I will bite. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19214007/308851) to the massively popular [Why does the C preprocessor interpret the word "linux" as the constant "1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1) question mentions that

```
main() { printf(&unix["\021%six\012\0"],(unix)["have"]+"fun"-0x60);}`
```

> prints `"unix"`, but for reasons that have absolutely nothing to do with the spelling of the macro name.

I read http://www.ioccc.org/1987/korn.hint but I think quite more detail would help unobfuscating this :)

Comment: This “question” presents a puzzle, not a question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Now a puzzle may puzzle people, and if people are puzzled, they tend to ask questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`unix` is 1 because of an implicit `#define` in the compiler or the runtime environment.

Thus, and because `a[b] == b[a] == *(a + b)` and thus `1["xy"] == "xy"[1]`, you get:

- `&unix["\021%six\012\0"]` points to `"%six\012\0"`
- `(unix)["have"] = "have"[1] = 'a'`,
- `"'a'+"fun"-0x60" = "fun" + 1 = "un"`.

This leads you to `printf("%six\012\0", "un");` which clearly does print `"unix\012"`, `\012` being a line break (the same as `\n`).

If `unix` is undefined, e. g. on a Windows system, you get an error.

If `unix` was `0` (can that ever be the way on a clean system?), you get

```
printf("\012%six\n", 'h'+"fun"-0x60)
```

where the 2nd argument is `"fun"+8`, pointing to Nirvana and leading to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I think it should print "unix" only when compiled under a unix-like system.

That's because on such systems, `unix` is a *predefined macro* with a value of `1`.

As such, it translates as:

```
main() { printf(&1["\021%six\012\0"], (1)["have"]+"fun"-0x60); }
```

Re-ordered to dispose of the `int[array]` nonsense, we get:

```
main() { printf(&"\021%six\012\0"[1], "have"[1] + "fun"-0x60); }
```

We can ignore the `\021` since it's skipped (I'll just replace it with a `?`), and translate the `\012` into `\n`:

```
main() { printf(&"?%six\n\0"[1], 'a' + "fun" - 0x60); }
main() { printf(  "%six\n",     0x61 + "fun" - 0x60); }
```

Which gives:

```
main() { printf("%six\n", "un"); }
```

**Note:** I was re-solving it as I went (especially the second part), but the first time I saw it I needed two hints to even understand the explanation:

- `unix` means `1`
- `int[array]` is an actual notation that the compiler accepts.