# Gcc preprocessor and pasting

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I found this snippet on stackoverflow the other day (thanks for that):

```
#define PLATFORM 3
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define PLATFORMSPECIFIC(fun) EVALUATOR(fun, PLATFORM)

extern void PLATFORMSPECIFIC(somefunc)(char *x);
```

Compiled with gcc -E, it results in:

```
# 1 "xx.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "xx.c"





extern void somefunc_3(char *x);
```

However:

```
#define PLATFORM linux
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define PLATFORMSPECIFIC(fun) EVALUATOR(fun, PLATFORM)

extern void PLATFORMSPECIFIC(somefunc)(char *x);
```

results in:

```
# 1 "xx.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "xx.c"





extern void somefunc_1(char *x);
```

What can I do to make this return 'somefunc_linux' ?. Clang seems to do it right, btw.

Comment: Also state your compiler versions. I get the same results with clang and gcc - as both compilers predefines a `#define linux 1`

Comment: Ah.. good call. I didn't check to see whether linux was predefined.

Comment: I thought that on Linux, it was only 'linux' with two underscores at either end. My bad.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1 - lots of discussion on this.

Comment: I think it's all the more reason to have a special token to mean 'evaluate this' - like, say, a dollar-sign or something. It works for shells...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use linux as a name, you can change your compiler options to undefine it:

```
gcc -Ulinux
```

or to be standards compliant:

```
gcc -std=c90 -pedantic ... # or -std=c89 or -ansi
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic
```

See more discussion about why here: [Why does the C preprocessor interpret the word "linux" as the constant "1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1)