# What will be output of following expression and why?

Tags: c, unix

```
printf(&unix["\021C%set"],(unix)["Chb"]+"Trick"-0X67);
```

It gives output as "Cricket". But I am not able to understand why?
http://ideone.com/fTEAHG

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19210935/827263

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unix` is a [predefined macro indicating it's a Unix-like system](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros).

In C, `index[array]` is identical to `array[index]`. As explained by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8.aspx):

> Usually, the value represented by *postfix-expression* is a pointer value, such as an array identifier, and *expression* is an integral value (including enumerated types). However, all that is required syntactically is that one of the expressions be of pointer type and the other be of integral type. Thus the integral value could be in the *postfix-expression* position and the pointer value could be in the brackets in the expression or subscript position.

So

```
printf(&unix["\021C%set"],(unix)["Chb"]+"Trick"-0X67);
```

translates to

```
printf(&"(\021C%set"[1]),"Chb"[1]+"Trick"-0X67);
```

`&("\021C%set"[1])` takes the address of the first element of "\021C%set", which is equivalent to taking the address of "C%set" (due to C pointer arithmetic).  Simplify that, and rearrange some operands:

```
printf("C%set","Trick"+"Chb"[1]-0X67);
```

`"Chb"[1]` is `'h'`, which is ASCII value 0x68, so `"Chb"[1]-0X67` is 1, and `"Trick"+1` is `"rick"` (due to C pointer arithmetic). So the code simplifies further to

```
printf("C%set","rick");
```

which prints "Cricket."

Comment: Can you clarify why `&("\021C%set"[1])` is the address of `"C%set"`? I didn't fully understand your explanation.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein - C strings are arrays of chars. So `"\021C%set"[1]` means element 1 of the array "\021C%set". Element 1 is 'C' (because element 0 is '\021'), so &("\021C%set"[1]) is the address of 'C' and the address of "C%set".

Comment: What does `\021` mean? I thought it meant the null-character followed by 2 and then 1.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein - It's an [octal escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Answer (score 1):

Well, `unix` is 1 in this implementation.  `a[b]` is something like `*(a+b)`, and `a+b` is somethng like `b+a`, so `&unix["\021C%set"]` is something like `&(*("\021C%set"+1))`.  Since `&(*(c))` is more or less just `c`, this gets you `"\021C%set"+1`, which is a pointer to the second character, so just `"C%set"`, which is a format string for "C" followed by a string followed by "et".  `\021` is an octal escape (which are 1 to 3 octal digits long; however many valid), so it only counts as one character.

Next we have `(unix)["Chb"]`, which for the same reasons is the same as "Chb"[1], which will be the int value of the 'h' character, which in ASCII is 104. On the other side, `0X67` is 103.  So we have `104+"Trick"-103`, or `"Trick"+1`.  This is the same pointer arithmetic on a string literal thing used on the left side, and it gets you "rick".

So we're left with:

```
printf("C%set", "rick");
```

Which prints "rick" between "C" and "et" (Cricket).