# Upgrading from C++98 to C++11 causes error

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cmake

I am using QT Creator to make a C++ program on Ubuntu. The program I had written was compiling fine, until I decided to start using C++11 rather than C++98 (which is the default in QT Creator). I am using my own cmake file, rather than qmake, and so to do this, I included the following line in my `CMakeLists.txt file`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
```

Now, part of my code has the following (which was not written by me):

```
#if (linux && (i386 || __x86_64__))
#   include "Linux-x86/OniPlatformLinux-x86.h"
#elif (linux && __arm__)
#   include "Linux-Arm/OniPlatformLinux-Arm.h"
#else
#   error Unsupported Platform!
#endif
```

After transferring to C++11, I get an error at the line `error Unsupported Platform!`. This is because, from what I can see, the variable `linux` is not defined anywhere, although the variable `__x86_64__` is defined.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1) Why is the variable `linux` not defined, even though I am using Linux?

2) How can I tell C++11 to ignore this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried only using `linux` without adding `__arm__`?

Comment: That doesn't work, because `linux` is not defined anywhere anyway. I have also tried replacing `linux` with `unix`, but that is still not defined.

Comment: is `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")` the only change you made?  Most C++98 code should compile fine in C++11 unless you relied on non standard behavior.

Comment: It is not the *only* change, because I have incorporated some code from elsewhere which uses some C++11 code (such as the double ampersand for rvalue reference), which is why I needed to upgrade. However, it is the only change to my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Have you tried to revert back all changes except changing the code in the makefile, and then let it compile?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the new file which uses the C++11 code, and remove the cmake line to upgrade to C++11, then it compiles fine. However, the `linux` variable is still not defined. Therefore, this still causes the error line to fire, but it just seems that C++11 is more strict than C++98 as to whether this is allowed. If I just remove the file using the C++11 code, and then add the cmake line to upgrade to C++11, then it doesn't compile, because the `linux` variable is undefined.

Comment: Then why don't you define it somewhere?

Comment: @user3528438: Because it should be defined by the compiler. Defining it yourself will break the portability you get from using it.

Comment: But I haven't had to define any of the other variables, such as `__x86_64__`. So, I assume that they are defined somewhere in this other code that I am using.

Comment: @Karnivaurus: Can you get CMake to print the compile command it uses? Assuming it's using GCC, you can add `-dM` to that to dump the predefined macros. That should contain `linux` if you're building for Linux, and `__x86_64__` if you're building for that, unless something weird has happened. Also, which compiler version are you using? If it's old enough that you need to specify `0x` rather than `11`, then its C++11 support might be a bit flaky.

Comment: I tried using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -dM")`, but that did not print anything out. Is that what you meant?

Comment: And as for my compiler version: `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`

Comment: touch empty.cpp; g++ -dM -E -std=c++0x empty.cpp  - this command should dump your defined macros.

Answer (score 5):

The identifier `linux` is not reserved. A conforming compiler may not predefine it as a macro. For example, this program:

```
int main() {
    int linux = 0;
    return linux;
}
```

is perfectly valid, and a conforming compiler must accept it. Predefining `linux` causes the declaration to be a syntax error.

Some older compilers (including the compiler you were using, with the options you were giving it) predefine certain symbols to provide information about the target platform -- including `linux` to indicate a Linux system. This convention goes back to early C compilers, written before there was a distinction between reserved and unreserved identifiers.

The identifier `__linux__`, since it starts with two underscores, is reserved for use by the implementation, so compilers are allowed to predefine it -- and compilers for Linux systems typically do predefine it as a macro expanding to `1`.

Confirm that your compiler predefines `__linux__`, and then change your code so it tests `__linux__` rather than `linux`.  You should also find out what reserved symbol is used instead of `i386` (likely `__i386__`).

Related: [Why does the C preprocessor interpret the word "linux" as the constant "1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19210935/827263)

Answer (score 0):

Change your standard-selection flag to `-std=gnu++0x` instead of `c++0x`. The `gnu` flavors provide some non-standard extensions, apparently including predefining the macro `linux`. Alternatively, check for `__linux__` instead.