# GCC Bug, "linux" string in path replaced with "1" when using "<>" angle brackets to include a header through a macro

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I may have found a bug in gcc. I couldn't find anything related to this online so I want to know if anyone seen this before.

I am using "Ubuntu 16.04.0 LTS" with:
`gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6)`, but this problem can be reproduced on later gcc versions as well, gcc-6 and gcc-7.

Here https://github.com/mihaipop11/gcc-linux you can find a link to a github repo containing all the sources but I'll also explain this below.

***How to reproduce:***

We have this nice little program with these files:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include INCLUDE_FILE

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Works this time" << std::endl;
}
```

and a header file inside a folder, let's say named `include`, doesn't matter that is empty, this is only for demonstration purposes.

```
// include.hpp
//empty header
```

Overall the structure looks like this:

```
<dir>
├── main.cpp
└── include
    └── include.hpp
```

***Compilation step:***

I analysed two cases and the bug appears in the second one.

**First case:**

The `<dir>` folder name which holds the files should be named anything but something that contains the string `linux`. ex: `test-notlinux`

Overall the structure looks like this:

```
test-notlinux
├── main.cpp
└── include
    └── include.hpp
```

Now, `cd test-notlinux` and try to compile the sources:

```
g++ "-D INCLUDE_FILE=\"${PWD}/include/include.hpp\"" main.cpp
g++ "-D INCLUDE_FILE=<${PWD}/include/include.hpp>" main.cpp
```

**Result:** Both commands work as expected. No issue here.

**Second case:**
The `<dir>` folder name which holds the files contains the string `linux`. ex: `test-linux`

Overall the structure looks like this:

```
test-linux
├── main.cpp
└── include
    └── include.hpp
```

Now, `cd test-linux` and try to compile the sources:

```
// first command should work
g++ "-D INCLUDE_FILE=\"${PWD}/include/include.hpp\"" main.cpp

// but this ...
g++ "-D INCLUDE_FILE=<${PWD}/include/include.hpp>" main.cpp
```

**Result:** The second command apparently replaces the `linux` string from the dir name with `1`

**Output:** `/tmp/test-1/include/include.hpp: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is. Maybe you could clearly state your question. If you are trying to file a GCC bug report, then try [GCC Bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).

Comment: I don't have much time to analyze but maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1

Comment: @ymonad thx, it seems related to that one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the C preprocessor interpret the word "linux" as the constant "1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210935/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-interpret-the-word-linux-as-the-constant-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that `linux` is a macro defined to `1`.  In <> case the macro is expanded while in "" case, the token is a string.

Second thing is that `linux` is a defined only when using the GNU extensions, so just compile with `-std=c++{98,11,14,17,2a}` or `-ansi` and it won't be defined (only `__linux__`, `__linux` and `__gnu_linux__` will be).

Comment: It's probably the answer for GCC, but IIRC the character sequence `#include "test-linux/include/include.hpp"` is **not** a string token, but a _header-name_, in particular a _q-char-sequence_. Formally that allows a compiler to accept `#include "C:\test"` without parsing `\t` as a tab character.